# Using accompaniment tracks on podcast

Tags: copyright

I own several accompaniment tracks that I use to sing with at churches etc.  Can I record myself singing and use that on my podcast (audio only)?

Comment: Who owns the copyright on those tracks?

Comment: @bdb484 and who owns the copyright on the melodies that would be sung with the tracks?

Comment: Different polices might have different laws on this question.

Answer (score 0):

### No

Your church should be paying performance-right royalties which is what allows those backing tracks and your vocals to be legally performed. Most countries’ copyright laws establish statutory schemes to allow places of public entertainment (schools, clubs, hotels, karaoke rooms, churches etc) to pay for and use copyrighted music without having to negotiate with each artist individually.

For a podcast, you might be able to use that scheme in the same way that radio and TV stations do. It will depend on the specifics of your local copyright law. If not, you will need to get permission from the copyright holders.

Note that you need permission from the copyright holders for the music (composer and performers), and for the lyrics (writer and you). These are typically licensed to the record company but for instrumental tracks only, that won’t necessarily mean they have a licence to the lyrics.